# Can I reduce this 3 functions to only one and create 3 distincts things?

Tags: javascript, simplify

These functions will create divs, and A, B, and C will have different left positions (as in the arrays) and different classes with different dimensions. Another function will call them in a set interval and will decrease all the "--bottom" with time at the same speed (they will move down ).
I have a feeling that these functions can be simplified to one, but I am new to javascript.

```js
function getCustomProperty(elem,prop){
    return parseFloat(getComputedStyle(elem).getPropertyValue(prop)) || 0
}

function setCustomProperty(elem,prop,value){
    elem.style.setProperty(prop, value)
}

function incrementCustomProperty(elem,prop,inc){
    setCustomProperty(elem,prop, getCustomProperty(elem,prop)+inc)
}
const worldElem = document.querySelector("[data-world]")
function createA() {
    let posits = [15,45,75]
    let posit = posits[Math.floor(Math.random()*posits.length)]
    const A = document.createElement("div")
    A.dataset.A = true
    A.classList.add("A")
    worldElem.append(A)
    setCustomProperty(A, "--bottom", 100)
    setCustomProperty(A, "--left", posit)
}
function createB() {
    let posits = [11.5,23.5,41.5,53.5,71.5,83.5]
    let posit = posits[Math.floor(Math.random()*posits.length)]
    const B = document.createElement("div")
    B.dataset.B = true
    B.classList.add("B")
    worldElem.append(B)
    setCustomProperty(B, "--bottom", 100)
    setCustomProperty(B, "--left", posit)
}

function createC() {
    let posits = [14,23.5,44,53.5,74,83.5]
    let posit = posits[Math.floor(Math.random()*posits.length)]
    const C = document.createElement("div")
    C.dataset.C = true
    C.classList.add("C")
    worldElem.append(C)
    setCustomProperty(C, "--bottom", 100)
    setCustomProperty(C, "--left", posit)
}
```

Comment: Great that you created a runnable snippet, but could you complete it with the needed code to actually make it run without errors?

Comment: @trincot Like this?

Comment: you could pass in `posits`, what is the data attribute used for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seem to be two varying values when comparing your three functions A, B, and C:

- the id ("A", "B" or "C")
- the `posits` array

So, you could pass that information as an argument to the function. Either as two separate arguments, or one object that combines that information.

For example:

```
function create(config) {
    let [[id, posits]] = Object.entries(config);
    let posit = posits[Math.floor(Math.random()*posits.length)];
    const div = document.createElement("div");
    div.dataset[id] = true;
    div.classList.add(id);
    worldElem.append(div);
    setCustomProperty(div, "--bottom", 100);
    setCustomProperty(div, "--left", posit);
}

var A = [15,45,75];
var B = [11.5,23.5,41.5,53.5,71.5,83.5];
var C = [14,23.5,44,53.5,74,83.5];

// Example calls:
create({A});
create({B});
create({C});
```